# Redirect OnItemClick on a ListView to the real touched Item view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a listview that shows a list of views for every row/Item (A list item can have for example 2 or 3 buttons). All Items are set to do not be focusable and not be clickable. This way clicks on the items call to my ListView OnClick. What I want to do now is call performClick() on the real clicked view (that did nothing because it was set as not focusasble/cickable). Is this possible? I have tried to find a method to get a view based on a click location and did not find anything and on the other hand onItemClick click handler for a list view seems not to get the x/y of the touch either. I know that for this I could use OnTouchEvent but then I won't be able to know what item was clicked, etc...

Comment: question is a bit confusing.. you want to perform onItemClick when some one clicks on any of the buttons? or vice versa?

Comment: Sorry. I mainly want that when user clicks on a view (for example a button) that belongs to a list view item (that have been set through the custom list data adapter) the one receiving the click was the list and not the button and after this notify the button that it was clicked in my custom list view item onclick handler through the performClick() or whatever. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: so u want to invoke both onClick event of both controls? right?

Comment: Yes, but the second onclick will be invoked by me manually. The flow is, more or less: 1) Setup a listview with a custom data adapter. 2) Set an onclickItem for the listview. 3) Make all the views created by the custom data adapter not clickable (for example 3 buttons). 4) When the list view is clicked we receive a OnItemClick event on the list. 5) Now we test what view was really clicked (one of the three button) and then we notify the button manually. Sorry for all the mess, but it is a bit hard to explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

okay try this, might help you... set a common onClick for buttons as well as the ListItem.

```
@override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Sting position=v.getTag().toString();               //<--- like this
    //task to do when clicks on the view...
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.<id_of_the_button1>:  
           //task to do when clicks on the button 1         
    break;
    case R.id.<id_of_the_button2>:  
           //task to do when clicks on the button 2         
    break;
}
```

implement OnClickListener in the custom adapter and over ride it with the above onClick.

Comment: Well, this might work, the problem is that I will need to know what position id (list item) for the list was clicked too to get some data that is there, etc... This is why I was using the List OnItemClick. Whith your method I know nothing about the item position in the list. In my case I need this because each item list is a different option in a menu.

Comment: set position as as tag while creating the list. using setTag() method. You can set tag for the list item view. ive edited the answer.